# Select submatrix and vectorize in one command in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, reshape, submatrix

Lets say we have an Array `A = ones(2, 2, 2)` and another matrix `P = rand(4)`. I am wondering if it is possible to write the code

```
temp = A(:, :, 1);
X = P * temp(:);
```

into one line of code to save the memory consumed by `temp`. I tried to run

```
X = P * A(:, :, 1)(:);
```

but that does not work. I also fumbled around with the `reshape` command but could not make it work.

I could not find the answer using the web or this forum. Is it possible to do what I am looking for?

Thank you for the help,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do -

```
[m,n,r] = size(A);
X = P*reshape(A(:,:,1),m*n,[])
```

If you are doing it iteratively along the third dimension of `A`, i.e. for `A(:, :, iter)`, where `iter` is the iterator, you could get all `X`'s in a vectorized manner in an array like so -

```
X_all = P*reshape(A,m*n,[])
```

Comment: Oh, that could work. I am actually doing it iteratively, so then I could even eliminate the for loop!

Comment: Yeah, that was basically my assumption there!

Comment: I just tried it and it works! Thanks a lot. This is the second time you helped me with a reshape problem! You are the reshape-master of matlab!!

Comment: @aeduG Well I don't remember helping you before, but I do like `reshape`. In other words, I do remember `reshape` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Reshape should work. Try doing it like this:

```
X = P * reshape(A(:, :, 1), [], 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this would have helped me too. I would also select your answer as correct if I could select more than one. Thanks